# How to write a retry function in Rust that involves async

Tags: rust, async-await

Let's say I have a function like below that could fail. The function is also async

```
async fn can_fail() -> Result<i32, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let random: u8 = rng.gen();
    if random % 2u8 == 0 {
        Ok(42)
    } else {
       Err("error".to_string().into())
    }
}
```

Now I will like to implement a `retry` function that can be used to retry a function like `can_fail`.

I came up with this in my attempt

```
fn retry<F: Fn() -> Result<i32, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>>(f: F, retries: i32) -> Result<i32, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>
    {
    let mut count = 0;
    loop {
        let result = f();

        if result.is_ok() {
            break result;
        } else {
            if count > retries {
             break result
            }
            count += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my attempt to use, I tried to put `can_fail` into a closure like this

```
    let my_closure: Box<dyn Fn() -> Result<i32, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>> = Box::new(|| {
        can_fail().await
    });
```

But this fails with the error

```
error[E0728]: `await` is only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks
   --> src/main.rs:208:19
    |
207 |     let my_closure: Box<dyn Fn() -> Result<i32, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>> = Box::new(|| {
    |                                                                                         -- this is not `async`
208 |         can_fail().await
    |                   ^^^^^^ only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks
```

So I am kinda stuck. So my question are:

1. Is the `retry` I came up with do the job? I cannot tell as I cannot even pass in a closure to it
2. How do I fix the *`await` is only allowed inside `async` functions and blocks`* error in this scenario?
3. Also is it possible to make retry maybe more generic? To get started I hard coded the return type of the function to be returned. In real life I would want that to be generic. How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `retry()` function looks OK, but to pass an async function into it you need to fix it to accept a function returning `Future`, and to be able to `.await` it, make it async:

```rust
async fn retry_async<Fut, F: Fn() -> Fut>(f: F, retries: i32) -> Result<i32, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>
where
    Fut: Future<Output = Result<i32, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>>,
{
    let mut count = 0;
    loop {
        let result = f().await;

        if result.is_ok() {
            break result;
        } else {
            if count > retries {
                break result;
            }
            count += 1;
        }
    }
}

retry(can_fail, 3).await.expect("failed to many times");
```

You can also make the function more generic by:

- Taking `FnMut` instead of `Fn`.
- Allowing a generic return type.
- Allowing a generic error type.

```rust
async fn retry_async<T, E, Fut, F: FnMut() -> Fut>(mut f: F, retries: i32) -> Result<T, E>
where
    Fut: Future<Output = Result<T, E>>,
{
    let mut count = 0;
    loop {
        let result = f().await;

        if result.is_ok() {
            break result;
        } else {
            if count > retries {
                break result;
            }
            count += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

TLDR: a function won't cut it, use a macro instead:

```rust
macro_rules! retry {
    ($f:expr, $count:expr, $interval:expr) => {{
        let mut retries = 0;
        let result = loop {
            let result = $f;
            if result.is_ok() {
                break result;
            } else if retries > $count {
                break result;
            } else {
                retries += 1;
                tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis($interval)).await;
            }
        };
        result
    }};
    ($f:expr) => {
        retry!($f, 5, 100)
    };
}
```

[Compiling example in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8b73528c520a3e9601aa2b0bdb4b157f)

---

## Using a function

### Limitations

The accepted answer suggests to pass an `FnMut` closure which returns a `Future` to the `retry` function. But that approach is limited to futures that don't capture their environment. For instance, this won't compile:

```rust
use core::convert::Infallible;
use core::future::Future;

async fn retry<T, E, Fut, F>(retries: usize, mut f: F) -> Result<T, E>
where
    F: FnMut() -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = Result<T, E>>,
{
    let mut count = 0;
    loop {
        let result = f().await;
        if result.is_ok() {
            return result;
        } else {
            count += 1;
            if count >= retries {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Foo {}

impl Foo {
    async fn call(&self) -> Result<(), Infallible> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
    async fn call_mut(&mut self) -> Result<(), Infallible> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

async fn do_things() {
    let mut foo = Foo {};
    // All good
    retry(1, || async { foo.call().await }).await.unwrap();
    // Boom
    retry(1, || async { foo.call_mut().await }).await.unwrap();
}
```

The problem here is this bit:

```rust
|| async { foo.call_mut().await }
```

We want the closure to be an `FnMut` so that:

- it can be called multiple times within `retry`
- it can mutate its environment, which *in theory* means we can use mutable variables in the `async` block. This is was we want here: `call_mut` requires a mutable reference to `foo`.

However:

```
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
  --> src/lib.rs:42:17
   |
38 |     let mut foo = Foo {};
   |         ------- variable defined here
...
42 |     retry(1, || async { foo.call_mut().await }).await.unwrap();
   |               - ^^^^^^^^---^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |               | |       |
   |               | |       variable captured here
   |               | returns an `async` block that contains a reference to a captured variable, which then escapes the closure body
   |               inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
   |
   = note: `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
   = note: ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape
```

The error message is quite clear: the `async` block needs a `&mut Foo`, so `foo` must be moved into the future, to guarantee the only reference to `foo` is held by the future. But by moving `foo` into the future, we move it out of the closure. If this was not the case, we could have a situation where the closure is called multiple times, creating multiple futures holding a `&mut Foo`, which is invalid in Rust.

Another way to look at it, is that this closure can only be called once. It is an `FnOnce`, whereas our `retry` function takes an `FnMut`.

### Making it work anyway

So the problem is that the compiler wants to prevents us from creating multiple futures that hold the same mutable reference to `foo`. However, we *know* that our `retry` function won't do such thing, since it waits for the future to complete before calling the closure again.

So we *could* make things work:

```rust
    let rc_foo = Rc::new(RefCell::new(foo));
    retry(1, || async { rc_foo.borrow_mut().call_mut().await })
        .await
        .unwrap();
```

Here, we've basically turned an `FnOnce` into an `Fn`. But that's arguably quite ugly, and need to be adapted to each case where we want to use `retry`.

### The language fix

What we need to express is that `retry` takes a closure that "lends" `foo` to the `Future` it returns. When the `Future` is dropped, `foo` is released, and the closure can be called again. This kind of `LendingFnMut` is being discussed and might be implemented once day:

- https://rust-lang.github.io/async-fundamentals-initiative/roadmap/async_closures.html#design-notes
- https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2023/05/09/giving-lending-and-async-closures/

## Macros to the rescue

The issue we just discussed can simply be avoided by using a macro. This has the advantage of making the `count` and `interval` arguments optional.

```rust
use core::convert::Infallible;

macro_rules! retry {
    ($f:expr, $count:expr, $interval:expr) => {{
        let mut retries = 0;
        let result = loop {
            let result = $f;
            if result.is_ok() {
                break result;
            } else if retries > $count {
                break result;
            } else {
                retries += 1;
                tokio::time::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis($interval)).await;
            }
        };
        result
    }};
    ($f:expr) => {
        retry!($f, 5, 100)
    };
}

struct Foo {}

impl Foo {
    async fn call(&self) -> Result<(), Infallible> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
    async fn call_mut(&mut self) -> Result<(), Infallible> {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

async fn do_things() {
    let mut foo = Foo {};
    retry!(foo.call().await).unwrap();
    retry!(foo.call_mut().await).unwrap();
}
```

The problem is that this limits the possibilities in terms of control flow, since you cannot have a `?` or `return` in the expression you pass to the macro:

```rust
retry! {{
    foo.call_mut().await?;
    foo.call_mut().await?;
    foo.call_mut().await?;
}}.unwrap()
```

will result in:

```
error[E0277]: the `?` operator can only be used in an async function that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `FromResidual`)
  --> src/lib.rs:39:25
   |
36 |   async fn do_things() {
   |  ______________________-
37 | |     let mut foo = Foo {};
38 | | retry! {{
39 | |     foo.call_mut().await?;
   | |                         ^ cannot use the `?` operator in an async function that returns `()`
...  |
42 | | }}.unwrap()
43 | | }
   | |_- this function should return `Result` or `Option` to accept `?`
```

So you'll have to do something like this instead:

```rust
retry!{
    async {
        foo.call_mut().await?;
        foo.call_mut().await
    }.await
};
```

---

For more discussion, see this [users.rust-lang.org thread](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/async-retry-function/105455)